# Changing MathKernel process priority on the startup

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp, kernel, windows, kernel-startup

In the *built-in* Documentation there is an example how it is possible to change the priority of the MathKernel process using `NetLink`: `NETLink/example/Part1/ProcessPriority` (not available online).

I wish to change the *default* priority of the MathKernel processes.

Is it possible to achieve this without initializing `NetLink`?

Answer (score 2):

There are two [documented](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/program/WolframKernel.html) ways to achieve this:

1. Create the [environment variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable) `MATHKERNELINIT` with value `-threadpriority=-1` (the number `-1` under Windows corresponds to the priority `Below Normal`). Under Windows a permanent environment variable can be created via  *System Properties* ► *Advanced system settings* ► *Advanced* ► *Environment Variables*.
   After creating this environment variable all the new MathKernel processes will have the priority `Below Normal` by default (and in all installed versions of *Mathematica*!). System reboot is not necessary.
2. Via the [Evaluation ► Kernel Configuration Options...](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/menuitem/KernelConfigurationOptions.html) dialog create a new kernel and in the `Advanced Options` add the `-threadpriority=-1` command line switch, then make this kernel the Default Kernel via the [Evaluation ► Default Kernel](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/menuitem/DefaultKernel.html) submenu. This will not affect the Notebooks configured to use other kernels.